# Cannot find innodb_page_size option in [mysqld] section in my.ini file

Tags: innodb, windows, mysql-8.0, my.ini

Where can I find `innodb_page_size` option? Since I cannot find it in `[mysqld]` section in `my.ini` file. I want to change it to 32k or 64k since I am getting the below error:

> MySQL: Error Code: 1118 Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help.

I know by default it is 16k. I am using MySQL Server 8.0.13, MySQL Workbench 8.0.13

Answer (score 0):

innodb_page_size can only be configured prior to initializing the MySQL instance and cannot be changed afterward. If no value is specified, the instance is initialized using the default page size. See Section 15.8.1, “InnoDB Startup Configuration”.

In other words - Include it your self and reboot Mysql